# Sitecore invoking Index() method from the Controller errantly

Tags: mvc, controller

I have a component whose assigned controller does not have an Index method. This is intentional, as the controller action is set to a specific action method.

Regardless, Sitecore still attempts to invoke the Index method and errors out because there is none:

> Could not invoke action method: Index. Controller name: Training.
>   Controller type:
>   {client name}.Website.Controllers.{client name}.Components.TrainingController

I've double checked the Controller and Controller Action component rendering settings are pointing the right place, and both these properties are properly assigned: (This was configured by someone else)

> Controller: {client name}.Website.Controllers.{client
>   name}.Components.TrainingController Controller Action:
>   TrainingListingComponent

The assigned action `TrainingListingComponent`:

```
public ActionResult TrainingListingComponent()
{
    var rendering = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering;
    var allItems = rendering.GetAllItemsFromFieldValue("Training Items");
    var model = CreateTrainingListModel(rendering.Parameters["Single Column"] == "1", allItems);
    model.RenderingItemId = rendering.Item.ID.Guid;            

    return View(GetViewDirectory("PageElements", "TrainingListingComponent"), model);
}
```

Am I missing an additional setting? Are there special requirements of controller which do not contain Index methods? Please assist.

Comment: Looks correct. And while this is not a proper fix, if you added an empty index() method to the controller, does the code then execute the right method without an error?

Comment: Try, not fully qualifying your controller definition. So just "Training" as opposed to Client.Website.etc.TrainingController.

Comment: Adding an empty Index() produces a C# error since the method returns no value.

Comment: Can you try to change the value in the controller field to have the entire namespace of your controller followed by the dll name.
for eg 
Controller: {client name}.Website.Controllers.{client name}.Components.TrainingController, dll name

Comment: Are you sure that there are no additional route definitions in your project?
Try search (ctrl+shift+F) for "Route" and check if there is anything defining a new route with an Index method as default or just hard-coded.

Comment: If you're struggling to find what might be calling it, you could create the method so that it least compiles and then break execution whilst debugging to inspect the stack trace, which will hopefully point to what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being something along the lines of Andrey Bobrov's suggestion:

> Are you sure that there are no additional route definitions in your
>   project? Try search (ctrl+shift+F) for "Route" and check if there is
>   anything defining a new route with an Index method as default or just
>   hard-coded.
>   I had defined a JSON service route that implemented the same path as the page I was tying to access. Changed the service route solved the issue quickly.